AWS Emr serverless spark: Live UI takes a few seconds to update due to its asynchronous nature. Please check again in a few seconds
Unable to see live spark ui on aws emr serverless spark jobs. Once job is completed, UI is available but not avaialble for the running jobs
Message:

Live UI takes a few seconds to update due to its asynchronous nature.
Please check again in a few seconds.

Note: spark.ui.enabled=true (UI is enabled for the jobs)
